# How do I backup and restore a dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20 system?

Tags: multi-boot

Is it feasible to use Norton Ghost, Onekey Ghost, Clonezilla or similar tools to backup and restore dual booting OS Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20?

If yes, how do I backup/restore them separately? Because I don’t want to restore Ubuntu just because Windows OS encounters some issues.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? Do it from a boot disk.

Comment: Other tools can be used, as well, e.g. Macrium Reflect Free. Make a full disk image, and in the event of an issue with either OS, partitions or the whole disk can be restored. This has saved me a *great* deal of trouble on numerous occasions.